# mapping T from DbSet<T> into Dabase internal representation using EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm a beginner in .NET and Entity Framework, just a question on the mapping, Lets say we have  Recipes class whose property is Ingredient, so we have two classes Recipes and Ingredient.

and we do the mapping by:

```
public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
```

so EF will examine the properties of Recipe and create a Recipes table and eventually it will find the Ingredient as a property, so it will create an Ingredient table.
so far it seems to be straightforward, but this is a very simple structure, so we know that Recipes contain Ingredient, so we don't do like

```
public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes { get; set; }
public DbSet<Ingredient> Ingredient { get; set; } //duplicated
```

but image that in a complicated app, we might have hundreds of classes, so when we do

```
public DbSet<T> T{ get; set; }
public DbSet<U> U{ get; set; }
public DbSet<V> V{ get; set; }
...
```

T might contain U as a property and U might contain V as a property,
so we just need to code like:

```
public DbSet<T> T{ get; set; }
```

so I am confused, should we include all the classes in the DbContext? if we do that, there will be duplicated declarations, but if we don't do that, we might lose a mapping.
so I guess we just do tat for all classes and expect EF to be smart enough to ignore duplicated thing?

Answer (score 0):

EF is smart enough to not create a duplicated tables, its best to inc all `DbSet<>`.

When you have a class with name `Ingredient` and you inc a reaference to it in `Recept` there will be only one Table with name `Ingredient` and you cant have two tables with the same name so no duplicated tables will be created even if you wanted too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be aware that your dbContext represents your database. The DbSets represent the tables in the database

> In entity framework the columns of the tables are represented by the non-virtual properties of your classes. The virtual properties represent the relations between the tables (one-to-many, many-to-many, ...)

Your database will have `Recipes` and `Ingredient`. Every `Recipe` will have zero or more `Ingredients`, while every `Ingredient` is used in zero or more `Recipes`: a straightforward many-to-many relationship.

You will have tables `Recipes` and `Ingredients`, so your dbContext will have `DbSets` for them:

```
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Recipe> Recipes {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Ingredient> Ingredients {get; set;}
}

class Recipe
{
    public int Id {get; set;}  // primary key
    ...                        // other columns

    // every Recipe has zero or more ingredients (many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Ingredient> Ingredients {get; set;}
}

class Ingredient
{
    public int Id {get; set;}  // primary key
    ...                        // other columns

    // every Ingredient is used in zero or more Recipes( many-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Recipe> Recipes {get; set;}
}
```

Because I used `virtual` on both sides, Recipes and Ingredients, entity framework can detect that I designed a many-to-many. Entity framework will even create a junction table for me, I won't have to declare it.

```
// Fetch all Desserts with their Bitter ingredients
var desertsWithoutSugar = myDbContext.Recipes
    .Where(recipe => recipy.Type == RecipyType.Dessert)
    .Select(recipe => new
    {
        // select only the properties that I plan to use:
        Id = recipe.Id,
        Name = recipe.Name,
        ...
        // not needed: you know the value: Type = recipe.Type

        Ingredients = recipe.Ingredients
           .Where(ingredient => ingredient.Taste == Taste.Bitter)
           .Select(ingredient => new
           {
               // again: only the properties you plan to use
               Id = ingredient.Id,
               Name = ingredient.Name,
           })
           .ToList(),
     })
```

Entity framework knows about your many-to-many relation and is smart enough to detect that a (group-)join is needed with three tables, inclusive the junction table.

If you want to design a one-to-many relationship, for instance a School with his Students, you declare the `virtual ICollection` only on one side. The other side gets the foreign key. This is a column in your table, and thus non-virtual

```
class School
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...                     

    // every School has zero or more Students (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students {get; set;}
}
class Student
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...   

    // Every Student studies at one School, using foreign key
    public int SchoolId {get; set;}
    public virtual School School {get; set;}
}
public SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<School> Schools {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Student> Students {get; set;}
}
```

In my experience, since I use entity framework, I hardly have to do a (Group-)join anymore, I use the collections:

> Give me all Schools with their Students

```
var Result = dbContext.Schools
    .Where(school => ...)
    .Select(school => new
    {
        Id = school.Id,
        ...

        Students = school.Students
            .Where(student => ...)
            .Select(student => new
            {
                 Id = student.Id,
                 ...
            })
            .ToList(),
    });
```

And similar: give me all students with the school they attend

Answer (score 0):

As you already said, EF will find `Ingredient` type among the `Recipe` properties and create the `Ingredients` table. This means, the `Ingredients` table will be created even if you leave out `public DbSet<Ingredient> Ingredient { get; set; }`. However, just because you don't need `public DbSet<Ingredient> Ingredient { get; set; }`, doesn't mean you mustn't have it. You can feel free to include it, and it will not do any harm, nor create any duplicates.

Adding `public DbSet<Ingredient> Ingredient { get; set; }` to your `DbContext` allows you to access the `Ingredient` entries directly from the context:

```cs
MyContext context = ...
var ingredients = context.Ingredients;
```

Otherwise, you would have to access the `Ingredient` entries through the `Recipes` property:

```cs
MyContext context = ...
var recipe = context.Recipes...;
var ingredients = recipe.Ingredients;
```

**Summary: When should you include the class in the DbContext?**

- When the class is not referenced by any other class that is part of the `DbContext`. Adding the class to the `DbContext` will make sure it's mapped.
- When you want to be able to access that class' entries directly from the DbContext instance. E.g. `var ingredients = context.Ingredients`.
- When you want to make sure the class will be mapped, and don't want to rely on it being referenced by some other mapped class.

So, to answer your question **"Should we include all the classes in the DbContext?"**:
You can, and it is totally fine approach. That way you will make sure all the classes (you want to be mapped) will be mapped, not having to rely on them being referenced by some other class.